# Access Kerberos protected REST service with CORS aproach

Tags: ruby, ajax, apache, kerberos, cors

I try to call cross domen REST service from Ajax.
To accomplish CORS i tried to put Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in service Aapache config.

  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"

When i switch of Kerberos protection from resource all is fine
And response header from server allows CORS

Access-Control-Allow-Cred...    true

Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    GET

Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    my_host

Access-Control-Max-Age  1728000

Problem starts when tunring on Kerberos protection on resource. Browser thinks that cross domen access is not allowed.
Response header:

ConnectionKeep-Alive

Content-Encodinggzip

Content-Length343

Content-Typetext/html; charset=iso-8859-1DateMon, 15 Oct 2012 14:05:43 GMT

Keep-Alivetimeout=5, max=100ServerApache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)VaryAccept-Encoding

WWW-AuthenticateNegotiate

Basic realm="Kerberos Login"

Does any way exist we could use CORS for cross domen request on Kerberos protected resources?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Does any way exist we could use CORS for cross domen request on Kerberos protected resources?

Comment: Well, this is CORS specific question. There is no problem with Kerberos performing cross-domain auth.

Comment: Actually it is XMLHttpRequest problem, it stops negotiaon when not reciving in response from server with header Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Maybe some way exist we can modify Apache server to send  header Access-Control-Allow-Origin with Kerberos negotiation request?

Comment: Well, then this is clearly a HTTP problem and not an auth problem. This should go to serverfault.com.

Comment: @MaksimSirotkin: Appending a header is very easy in Apache: use `<Location>` + [`mod_headers`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html). Perhaps you'd use `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin ...` inside `<Proxy>`.